# How can I direct output from a program to the console and a log file at same time?

Tags: bash, redirect, stdout

How can I print the output to terminal and file at the same time?

```
$ perl foo.pl > foout.txt
```

does not allow me to see live process.

Is there any way I can see the output process real time and getting at the end the output of the screen on a file?

Comment: Do you need to do this in your program or do you want to occasionally use shell facilities when you run your program? If the latter, the question should not have been tagged [perl] but rather with the shell and environment you are using.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`perl foo.pl |` [`tee`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tee) `foout.txt`

Comment: Retagging your question as accepting this answer shows that this was not a Perl question.

Comment: @Sinan: I'm adding the tag [perl] back in since people browsing the site for [perl] and [tee] should be able to find it either way. And as the responses make clear, you can do it with `tee` if it's available or within Perl itself (perhaps to make it more portable, etc.).

Answer (score 9):

The utility [tee](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tee) will do that.

Answer (score 7):

See [IO::Tee](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/IO::Tee). This module will allow you to do this selectively with fine grained control within your program (there is also a less mature module called [File::Tee](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/File::Tee) which worked for me once but I would not recommend that for any serious project).

See also [Log4perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Log-Log4perl/) for really fine grained control over what gets logged where and how.

For one off usage from the command line, as others have recommended, you can, of course, utilize the command line utility `tee` if you have access to it.

Comment: I've always used IO::Tee for this sort of thing. If you have experience with both, how would you compare them. (I'm looking now at the docs for File::Tee, but I'm curious if you have any input.)

Comment: @Telemachus I have rarely used File::Tee and never used IO::Tee so I am not in a position to do a comparison between the two. File::Tee worked nicely when I needed it. On the other hand, Log4perl is wonderful.

Comment: @Sinan: Fair enough. I will take a look at File::Tee and compare myself. I just figured I would ask.

Comment: @Telemachus My guess is I got lucky when I used it (it wasn't anything serious). If I ever said "oh where is tee for Perl" again, I would go with IO::Tee.

Comment: @Telemachus Oh, I did not know File-Tee did not work on Windows. Goes to show you ... I am going to drop my recommendation for File::Tee.

Comment: Log4perl is the best for me. Easy way to filter out and redirect specified writings to configured and rotated output files. Then we decide what we want log

Answer (score 0):

Or you could pipe it into a perl programs to print to the screen and a log file (that is if you are not on Unix or have a tee program)

perl foo.pl | perl myPipe.pl myFile.txt

where the data is captureed to myFile.txt and

myPipe.pl is

```
#
open OUTFILE,">$ARGV[0]" or die "Unable to open file: $ARGV[0]\n";

while(<>)
{
    print;
    print OUTFILE;
}
close OUTFILE;
```

This reads a line of input from STDIN and prints it to the screen and then to the file.  When the end is reached, it will close the file

Comment: heh. you developed wheel :)